# Is there a way to configure a job in Backup Exec 12.5 to eject a tape at a certain time no matter what

Tags: backupexec, lto-3

I know I can have a backup job eject a tape after a job completes. I have Differentials going to a single tape mulitple days per week. Is there any way to create a job just to eject a tape without writing new data or is my only option to create a new backup job set to backup some small file and use the eject tape at end option?

I'm concerned if the dummy backup fails due to a full tape, write protected tape, etcetera that Backup Exec will just consider the job failed and not eject the tape as failed doesn't equal completed.

So either positive answer would be good.

1. a method to eject the tape on schedule no matter what
2. a dummy backup job would eject the tape even if the backup "fails"

TonyUser has given me a way to do 1. I'm afraid 2 might not be possible. Assuming no better answer is given I'll just leave a scheduled task to run weekly doing "c:\program files\Symantec\Backup Exec\bemcmd" -o115 -d"HP 1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about running the [command line](http://seer.entsupport.symantec.com/docs/270246.htm) tool BEMCMD as a scheduled task:

> for Backup Exec 11.x and above
>   c:\program files\Symantec\Backup Exec\bemcmd -o115 -d"HP 1"`
>   where C: is the drive where Backup Exec has been installed
>   -o115 is for creating an eject job
>   HP 1 is the device name

Or [RMS](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rsm.mspx?mfr=true) might also work.

Comment: That might just be perfect. I was able to make it work using "c:\program files\Symantec\Backup Exec\bemcmd" -o115 -d"HP 1" (note the extra pair of quotes around the path to the executable) It makes a job that shows in the job monitor I just wonder why they don't allow you to create a job like that in the UI and schedule it there. At least I can use Windows Scheduled Tasks to run the command line automatically.

Oh wait. I just saw the run post job command even if the main job fails check box. Now I just need to figure out a job that will fail no matter what and I can use the UI to schedule it.

Comment: I'm afraid if I schedule a backup or restore job it will occasionally stall asking for media. I guess its going to be windows scheduled tasks for this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to export a specific slot, you can set a schedule for an Export job to run. In the Slots listing in the Device tab you can right-click on a slot and set this up.